# SQL order by included character and string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and i want to colum joint_no column. The column's values are like these

```
FW-1 
FW-2
.
.
.
FW-13
FW-R1
FW-1A
```

When i ordered them i get this results

```
FW-1
FW-10
FW-11
FW-12
FW-13
FW-1A
.
.
FW-R1
```

I want to get this result after sql query

```
FW-1
FW-1A
FW-2
FW-3
..
FW-13
FW-R1
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Patindex to find the first numeric expression as first sort field, then extracting the numeric part as integer as second sortfield and using the whole string as third sort field you might get the desired result.

```
Declare @a Table (c varchar(50))
Insert Into @a
Select 'FW-1'
Union Select 'FW-10'
Union Select 'FW-11'
Union Select 'FW-12'
Union Select 'FW-13'
Union Select 'FW-1A'
Union Select 'FW-2'
Union Select 'FW-3'
Union Select 'FW-R1'
Union Select 'FW-A1'
;With CTE as
(Select 1 as ID
Union All
Select ID + 1 from CTE where ID < 100
)

Select * from
(
Select c
 ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',c) as s1
 ,(Select Cast(
          (Select Case
                   When SUBSTRING(c, ID, 1) LIKE '[0-9]'
                   Then SUBSTRING(c, ID, 1)
                   Else ''
                  End
          From (Select * from CTE) AS X(ID)
          Where ID <= LEN(c)
          For XML PATH('')) 
          as int)
   )
  as s2
 from
@a
) x
order by
s1,s2,c
```

With the output:

```
FW-1    4   1   -1
FW-1A   4   1   -1A
FW-2    4   2   -2
FW-3    4   3   -3
FW-10   4   10  -10
FW-11   4   11  -11
FW-12   4   12  -12
FW-13   4   13  -13
FW-A1   5   1   A1
FW-R1   5   1   R1
```

If the leading part is not fixed (FW-) you might need to add one additional sort field

```
Declare @a Table (c varchar(50))
Insert Into @a
Select 'FW-1'
Union Select 'FW-10'
Union Select 'FW-11'
Union Select 'FW-12'
Union Select 'FW-13'
Union Select 'FW-1A'
Union Select 'FW-2'
Union Select 'FW-3'
Union Select 'FW-R1'
Union Select 'FW-A1'
Union Select 'AB-A1'
Union Select 'AB-11'
;With CTE as
(Select 1 as ID
Union All
Select ID + 1 from CTE where ID < 100
)

Select * from
(
Select c
 ,SubString(c,1,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',c)-1) as S0
 ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',c) as s1
 ,(Select Cast(
          (Select Case
                   When SUBSTRING(c, ID, 1) LIKE '[0-9]'
                   Then SUBSTRING(c, ID, 1)
                   Else ''
                  End
          From (Select * from CTE) AS X(ID)
          Where ID <= LEN(c)
          For XML PATH('')) 
          as int)
   )
  as s2
 from
@a
) x
order by
s0,s1,s2,c
```

Comment: Thanks your queries are very good. It will save my life :P . Now I am using this order by query 
order by (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(joint_no, 4, 5))=1 THEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(joint_no, 4, 3) AS INT)) end)
it will help me to order only numeric columns

Comment: My answer is only showing how (techincal) you would be able to do it, the advice of @Philippe-Grondier would be more useful for you.

Comment: my table name is fabrication_table
my column -i want to order- name is joint no
can u modify this table for me. It will be very very good for me. And I will win many times if it will be done :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can do it, I'd advise you to renumber the values so that the 'logical'  order sticks to the alphabetical order.  F-1 will then be updated to F-01, or F-001.

If you cannot do it, add a field that will be populated with the 'ordered'  form of your code. You 'll then be able to order by the F-001 column and still display the F-1 value

Otherwise ordering your records will rapidly become your nightmare.